# How to insert emoji into SQL Server using PHP and mssql_connect?

Tags: php, sql-server, unicode, emoji, php-mssql

I'm trying to insert emoji into `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column from PHP but I get error. The same query executed by SQL Server client works fine so the problem is query/connection size.

```
INSERT INTO table (text) VALUES (N' example')
```

I get error:

> Incorrect syntax near ''

I'm using PHP mssql_connect driver with mssql.charset set to UTF-8.

PHP version 5.6
SQL Server version 2016

Comment: The PHP code will help us. If possible, post your PHP script(s). Also, `mssql_connect` is part of the old and unsupported MSSQL driver for SQL Server. A better option is to use PDO and PHP Driver for SQL Server.

Comment: What sorting do you use in the database/table?

Comment: Your SQL (apart from the undelimit identified reserved keyword for an object name) works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64f72011f4fcab9c4ba359a88eba431b)